# Is it possible to change the value of a static const class member by template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I don't really know the terminology on this, I'll just do an example:

```
template <typename T>
struct value_holder {
    T value;
    static const bool is_integer = ??; // if T is int or long set this to true, else set false
}
```

so that when I do

```
value_holder<float> floaty;
std::cout << floaty.is_integer << "\n";
```

it would print 0

How would I have to define the member is_integer so it would do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::is_same` to do that.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct value_holder {
    T value;
    static const bool is_integer = std::is_same<int, T>::value or std::is_same<long, T>::value;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(value_holder<int>::is_integer, "!");
    static_assert(not value_holder<char>::is_integer, "!");
}
```

Another possible approach is based on template specialization. Something along this way should work:

```
template <typename T>
struct value_holder {
    T value;
    static const bool is_integer = false;
};

template <>
struct value_holder<int> {
    int value;
    static const bool is_integer = true;
};

template <>
struct value_holder<long> {
    long value;
    static const bool is_integer = true;
};
```

Anyway it's a bit more verbose from my point of view and can be annoying if your class contains more than a couple data members.

Answer (score 2):

As Quentin's answer says, you use a type trait.  `std::is_integral` makes sense in your example:

```
template <typename T>
struct value_holder {
    T value;
    static constexpr bool is_integer = std::is_integral<T>::value;
};
```

That doesn't exactly match your comment though.  If you really want to have `is_integer` be true only for `int` or `long` then you could define a custom type trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_int_or_long : std::false_type {};

template <>
struct is_int_or_long<int> : std::true_type {};

template <>
struct is_int_or_long<long> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct value_holder {
    T value;
    static constexpr bool is_integer = is_int_or_long<T>::value;
};
```

Of course, that could be shortened by using the `std::is_same` trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct value_holder {
    T value;
    static constexpr bool is_integer = std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, long>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for *type traits*. [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) might be of interest to you.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to perform template-specialization.

Comment: @Dai Even if template specialization could be used here, I'm pretty sure a type trait fits best.

Comment: maybe my example was bad but I was just trying to make it short - I don't actually want to check whether or not it is integral but just generally define static const members based on the template type

Comment: @user81993 yes -- and the technique you're looking for is called "type traits". There's a collection of them in the standard library, and you can also take inspiration and write your own (some of the cppreference pages contain sample implementations).